# Local audio files would NOT play in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, mp3, html5-audio

I'm having a hard time trying to play some local mp3 files using Google Chrome (>57):

Playing directly in Chrome it doesn't work - the controls are grayed out;

Including an HTML5 audio element in page - same result. The code is below:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="[filename].mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

My web server: Centos 6.5 running Apache 2.2

The audio files (mp3s) are just simple recordings no bigger than 5MB, 128 kbps.

The permissions of the files shouldn't be the issue (777).

Also, I added a .htaccess file that has these directives:

> AddType audio/mpeg .mp3
>
> Header set Accept-Ranges none

The same thing happens with .ogg files.

No error is thrown.

Everything works fine in Firefox, Edge, IE11.

The only way I can make it work is to serve the mp3 files (the same ones) from another location (external, another box) - so definitely is something wrong with my box. But what?